# Remove a an 'inner' list inside of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I am working with pokeapi lately and im trying to filter some values out of it.
The JSON im working on is this one: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/golduck/.

What I need from this is to either find a way to remove the list 'version_group_details' that's inside the big list ['moves'] when the level_learned_at dictionary key has a value of 0 OR when the move_learn_method is NOT level-up. And then create a new list with this information, just with those specific keys and values.

My focus here is to just get a clean list of dictionaries with the moves that have a level-up   value that's higher than 0. (I'm trying to make a little table with only abilities learned by level-up).

Any assistance would be appreciated!

editing with the code I have now:

self.moves is just this: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/golduck/

```
        
        jsonfile = self.moves
        move = jsonfile['moves']
        lst = list(self.__evo_generator(move, 'move'))

        return lst
```

This would be what 'gets' me the abilities and the following is the generator im calling:

```
    def __evo_generatortwo(self):

        req = request.Request(
        self.moves,
        data=None,
        headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
        }
        )

        with request.urlopen(req) as r:
            data = loads(r.read())

        moves = [
            m['move']['name']
            for m in data['moves']
            if any(d['level_learned_at'] > 0 and d['move_learn_method']['name']=='level-up'
                for d in m['version_group_details'])
        ]
        print(moves)


UPDATED CODE

Up above I updated how the looks, although i am getting the following error: URLError
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: {'abilities'>

What could be the cause to this? Or did I make some mistakes when replacing the values with mine?

(I did go with the single list statement option since I don't feel confident enough to mess around with generators, haha)
```

Comment: Yes I just did that, sorry! I dont know why I didnt think of that before.

Comment: Since moves have multiple 'version_group_details', some of which may be 'level-up', while others may be something like 'tutor', do you just want to list all the moves that *could* be learned by leveling up, even if they could also be learnt in other ways? There are also many multiples, apparently for different 'version_group's - do you want a specific one, any of them, or all of them?

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to isolate the level-up methods, since if I can do that, then I can just make another table with only other methods and so on, so yes, even if they can be learned in a different way, just the leveling ones would work. The version group doesn't  really matter much to me as of now, so getting the 'first' one available should be more than fine. 

I was also planning on doing some extra logic as if, for example, X pokemon belongs to X game, so it should always check that, but as of now I'm content with just getting the level up methods.

Comment: It looks like you stuck all of the solution in your method, but all you needed was the body of the function in the answer - you should try to understand how and why the code works, and not just copy and paste bits of code and hope for the best. Code can do serious damage if you just run it without understanding what it does.

Comment: I should have specified that I didnt wanna change much of the other generator function so I tried amking another one, but I think I completely failed at it. What you meant to explain in the below code was that: 

def __evo_generator(moves):

is meant to be called by :

for m in __evo_generator(data['moves']):
    print(m)

Correct?

Yeah, generators basically broke my mind honestly... same with list comprehensions, do you have any resources I could look into to see if I can understand this a little bit better? Also if possible, could you explain what 'data' is for in your code?

Comment: My code loads the entire content of the page you linked into data, as a dictionary (using `json.loads` to turn the text into a useful data structure). So, my `data['moves']` is the same as your `move` (supposedly, since you didn't show where it's coming from, but it appears that way)

Comment: I can't really recommend any specific resources on learning about comprehensions, it also depends on how you prefer to learn. But if you google 'comprehensions python', there's plenty of simple tutorials and guides that should get you started. Start small and simple, work your way up to the level you need here.

Comment: Oh! it actually works now! understanding that was the key! Again, I really appreciate the help and the explanation aswell. It means a lot! I've seen you reply to many different threads and I'm sure the community values it a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need any move that could be learned by leveling up, at any level (except 0) and without additional constraints:

```
from json import loads
from urllib import request

req = request.Request(
    'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/golduck/',
    data=None,
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
    }
)

with request.urlopen(req) as r:
    data = loads(r.read())


def __evo_generator(moves):
    for m in moves:
        if any(d['level_learned_at'] > 0 and d['move_learn_method']['name']=='level-up' for d in m['version_group_details']):
            yield m['move']['name']


for m in __evo_generator(data['moves']):
    print(m)
```

Note that I've removed the `self`, since you didn't provide the rest of the code of the class, but you can of course turn the function into a method. And since the key is really a two-parter ('move' and 'name'), I've left it out, but you could add that back in.

I wrote the function as a generator, since that was the route you were on, but you could also get the moves as a list in a single statement:

```
moves = [
    m['move']['name']
    for m in data['moves']
    if any(d['level_learned_at'] > 0 and d['move_learn_method']['name']=='level-up'
           for d in m['version_group_details'])
]
print(moves)
```

Edit: The first code example in the answer is intended to run all by itself, however in your original code, you probably only need the `__evo_generator` generator, or the second bit of code instead of it.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks! Yes, self, is basically just a function that returns the url I posted up top since it has to check for pokemon input, etc.

Comment: Oh I used a generator because that was the only solution I could find from more experienced programmers, I was a little stumbled otherwise, still trying to replace all the values in my code but I really appreciate the help!

Comment: That's alright, generators and classes with methods have their place, but you probably want to start out with the core Python stuff, like these comprehensions. Try to fully understand how and why the solution I posted works, and you'll be able to apply it to many Python problems, without complications that (in this case) aren't needed and will get in the way of understanding the language. You're welcome :).

Comment: By the way, if the solution is what you needed, feel free to check the mark next to the answer, so that your question no longer appears unanswered. If you're not clear on the solution, or it doesn't work as expected, feel free to comment, or add information to your question.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep trying since I'm sure this works. I really appreciate the patience